# AWS STS AssumeRole from SSO-generated role

Tags: amazon-web-services, sts, assume-role

I have an role which I would like to be assumable by a user logged in via SSO. The user’s role generated by SSO in the account is suffixed with a 16 digit hex string which is (as far as I can tell) random and therefor non-determinable at the point I construct the trust policy for the assumed role.

I came up with the following as a workaround for the fact that I can’t know the precise principal ARN:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "CanBeASsumedByMyPermissionSet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2/AWSReservedSSO_MyPermissionSet_*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This works for me, however, I get the following warning in the IAM console for the target role:

> Overly permissive trust policy exists in your trust relationships.
> Broad access: Principals that include a wildcard (*, ?) can be overly permissive.

It is also causing alerts in our 3rd-party monitoring.

Is there a better way that doesn't trigger this warning?